# Convert string representation of array back to int array in java

Tags: java, arrays

just started programming with Java. If I have an array as follows stored in a .txt file:

```
[10, 22, 30, 55, 10, 20, 19]
```

How do I convert it back to a normal int[] array to be used within the code?

I need to be able to store it plainly in a txt file like this so I can make changes to it manually. I've used BufferedReader to read the array. How can I put the read array into an int[] array?

```
int[] field;    
try {
    String line;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(gameFilePath));
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) { // Read the first line and assume it is the stored array
        field = line;
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Convert it? You probably want to read the file's contents.

Comment: I've tried ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream but these serialise the array data

Comment: I've read the file's contents. I need to put the string representation of the array into an int[] array as I've said already

Comment: Yes, after your edit that's clear. Please edit your post to show that code and explain clearly what problem(s) you're having.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting String to Int in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if your line is

```
[10, 22, 30, 55, 10, 20, 19]
```

then you can do

```
line = line.replace ("[", "");
line = line.replace ("]", "");
```

then you can use String.split

```
String vals [] = line.split (",");
```

then for each `val` you can use

```
intVal [x] = Integer.valueOf (val[x].trim ());
```

Answer (score -2):

What you're talking about doing is parsing the text.  A simple way to implement this yourself for a beginner if you know the structure of the text is to hard code the rules for reading in a function and use Scanner.

I'm on my phone so I'll put details later but there's tons of info on how to do that if I'm not in time